# How to debug presto server project?

Tags: presto

I am trying to debug presto server on eclipse with following steps,
com.facebook.presto.PrestoServer class > set debug break point inside main method. 
but, following errors are coming.

1) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManager is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManager
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.GracefulShutdownHandler.(GracefulShutdownHandler.java:66)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.GracefulShutdownModule.setup(GracefulShutdownModule.java:27)

Comment: That error shouldn't be possible.  Assuming this is not a custom build of Presto, I suggest you file an issue with the Presto project.  Make sure to include the Presto version and the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to follow the https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/README.md#running-presto-in-your-ide

In case if you would like attach a debugger to a server from existing Presto installation, please add the below to jvm.config file (see https://prestosql.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html#jvm-config), restart Presto server and then attach the debugger:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Comment: I added -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 in to jvm.config file and restart presto-server, then debug PrestoServer class under presto-main module but, same errors are coming.

Comment: sorry, debug mode started here but same errors are coming while to start presto-server.