# How to debug presto-server from eclipse?

Tags: presto

I am trying to debug presto server from eclipse IDE. But i am getting following errors,

2018-09-12T09:41:18.093+0530    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManager is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManager
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.GracefulShutdownHandler.(GracefulShutdownHandler.java:61)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.GracefulShutdownModule.setup(GracefulShutdownModule.java:27)

2) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig
    for the 2nd parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createAsyncHttpResponseExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:561)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createAsyncHttpResponseExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:561)

3) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createAsyncHttpTimeoutExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:569)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createAsyncHttpTimeoutExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:569)

4) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig
    for the 2nd parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createStatementResponseExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:585)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createStatementResponseExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:585)

5) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskManagerConfig
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createStatementTimeoutExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:593)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createStatementTimeoutExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:593)

6) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager
    for the 2nd parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createTransactionManager(ServerMainModule.java:620)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createTransactionManager(ServerMainModule.java:620)

7) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.metadata.Metadata is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.metadata.Metadata
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createNewStatsCalculator(ServerMainModule.java:517)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createNewStatsCalculator(ServerMainModule.java:517)

8) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.operator.ExchangeClientConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.operator.ExchangeClientConfig
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createExchangeExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:545)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createExchangeExecutor(ServerMainModule.java:545)

9) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.transaction.TransactionManagerConfig is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.transaction.TransactionManagerConfig
    for the 1st parameter of com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createTransactionManager(ServerMainModule.java:620)
  at com.facebook.presto.server.ServerMainModule.createTransactionManager(ServerMainModule.java:620)

10) Error: Invalid configuration property node.environment: may not be null (for class io.airlift.node.NodeConfig.environment)

11) Error: Invalid configuration property presto.version: presto.version must be provided when it cannot be automatically determined (for class com.facebook.presto.server.ServerConfig.prestoVersion)

If i execute same project from linux comman line, it work fine. please give me a idea to run and debug it from eclipse IDE.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/prestodb/presto/#running-presto-in-your-ide for instructions how to run Presto in IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug presto server project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143898/how-to-debug-presto-server-project)